# How can I generate dynamic React markup

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to convert the output from a free text comment field into a formatted component. I have an array of substitution strings which I would like to replace within the text and attach click handlers to as well. I'm struggling to think of a nice way to do it, I don't really want to go down the `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` route if possible. Here's what I started to work on but didn't get very far with:

```
  const FormattedComment = () => {
    const comment = 'Some info about 1A and 2A... maybe 1A again.';
    const substitutions = ['1A', '2A', '3A'];
    const subPostions: { sub: string; pos: number }[] = [];

    for (const sub of substitutions) {
      // this won't handle duplicates :(
      const pos = comment.indexOf(sub);
      if (pos >= 0) {
        subPostions.push({ sub, pos });
      }
    }

    // do something here (map? forEach?)
  };
```

In the hope that I could produce something like this (or better):

```
  <>
    <span>Some info about </span>
    <strong onClick={() => {}}>1A</strong>
    <span> and </span>
    <strong onClick={() => {}}>2A</strong>
    <span>... maybe </span>
    <strong onClick={() => {}}>1A</strong>
    <span> again.</span>
  </>
```

Any suggestions or working examples would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi!
Please take a look at my answer. It's work much better now and I think it will solve your problem :)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66755456/15388890

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use regular expressions for doing this. I created a sandbox for it:
https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-sea-tfxpk?file=/src/App.js

**EDIT:**

I updated my solution. It's much simpler now works great.
Additionally, it is a better approach from a performance standpoint as it does not create an array from all the words in the string, but only from those that are needed.

```
let comment = "Some info about 1A and 2A maybe 1A again.";
  const substitutions = ["1A", "2A", "3A"];

  const parts = comment.split(
    new RegExp(
      String.raw`(\b${String(substitutions).replaceAll(",", "|")}+\b)`,
      "gi"
    )
  );

  for (let i = 1; i < parts.length; i += 2) {
    parts[i] = <strong key={i}>{parts[i]}</strong>;
  }

  return <div className="App">{parts}</div>;
```

Comment: This is great, thanks Bart - much appreciated.

Comment: Just in case anyone wanted to see the solution working in the wild https://www.mycrossword.co.uk/crosswords/cryptic/16 - you'll need to scroll down to the comments section.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe by having a word array your problem can be solved:

```
...
const comment = 'Some info about 1A and 2A... maybe 1A again.';
const words = comment.split(" ");

return (
<>
  {
    words.map((word, index) => {
      if(substitutions.includes(word)
        return <strong key={`${word}-${index}`} onClick={() => {}}>{word}</strong>;
      else
        return <span key={`${word}-${index}`}>{word}{index < words.length-1 ? ' ' : ''}</span>;
    })
  }
</>
)

...
```

Have in mind that with this approach you would have more span tags than you put in the example.

Comment: You forget about adding `key` attributes to JSX elements inside `map()`.

Comment: Thanks Fabio, that looks like a nice straightforward approach. One question being, would you expect there to be a performance hit if there were 50+ comments being shown (each comment can be 500 characters too). Another quick question, is there a good method of safeguarding against partial matches? For instance, 1A can be found in 21A.

Comment: Good point. For performance you wouldn't want to calculate words ( specially the .split() ) every render. For this I recommend [useMemo hook](https://usehooks.com/useMemo/), which would let you save the words array if you already calculated it for the comment. About partial matches my approach already solves this, as `subtitutions` wouldn't include 21A, Is this what you expect?

Comment: Thanks @PavloZhukov , I added the key. Also I added logic so there's no trailing space on the last word.

Comment: Sorry Fabio, a) I didn't explain that particularly well and b) I misunderstood what `includes` does. Now that I've read the spec, I can now see that it performs complete matches, so you're right about that. I suppose one potential problem I can see is that splitting on a space wouldn't catch all cases e.g. I think "2A..." would be one of the elements in the array and fail the includes check (?). Nevertheless, I have accepted Bart's solution as it only splits the comment at the necessary points but I really appreciate you taking the time to investigate. Thanks!

Comment: I understand. Thank you for letting me know and glad We both could give you different approachs for you to learn